# Gitlab CI does not retain node_modules of other directory between jobs

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to trigger continuous deployment for my Express API and React app stored in one repo using Gitlab CI. I am using shell executor.

That's my directory structure

```
/server
/client
.gitlab-ci.yml
```

My config looks like this:

```
stages:
  - deploy

server:
  stage: deploy
  script: 
    - npm run start
    - forever restartall
  only:
    refs: 
      - staging
    changes:
      - server/

client:
  script: 
    - npm run build --prefix ./client
  stage: deploy
  only:
    refs: 
      - staging
    changes:
      - client/
```

But when client job runs, it cleans node_modules of the server folder which crashes the server.

I want a way in which node_modules are retained. Or any other way I can build server and client both together using Gitlab CI/CD

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the folders you want to keep at each stage:

```
server:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     - ....
 artifacts:
    paths:
        - node_modules/
        - bower/
        - ....
```

All artifacts will be transported from one stage to another. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#artifacts for more information